# Internet download manager download .mkv file as .mk3d

Tags: download-manager

i have an issue whenever i download a file with mkv format using idm it always saved as mk3d. When i download using the browser it save with correct format(mkv). What seems to be the problem?

I need to add mk3d at the option first so idm can catch the download, if i remove the mk3d from the option idm won't catch the download and use the browser instead.

I tried looking into the option but there are none as i can see(maybe missed it) related to the problem.
I tried looking my problem up and there is no similar problem i can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the mk3d registry from "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" will solve the problem.
how to:

- press windows + r key on keyboard.
- type "regedit" without quote.
- expand the "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" directory.
- find "mk3d" directory and delete it.